# Please explain how this code works for Matrix Transpose with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map

I was trying to solve for a Matrix Transpose problem which should have the expected output as this example:

```
makeTranspose([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]) ➞ [
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [3, 6, 9]
]
```

This is my solution and I understand what it is doing.

```js
function makeTranspose(butt) {
  var m=[];
  m = new Array(butt[0].length);
  for (let i=0; i < m.length;i++) {
    m[i] =new Array(butt.length);
    for ( let j=0;j<butt.length;j++) {
      m[i][j]=butt[j][i];
    }
  }
return m;
}

let result = makeTranspose([ [1, 2, 3]
                           , [4, 5, 6]
                           , [7, 8, 9]
                           ])
                          
result.forEach( line => console.log (JSON.stringify(line)))
```

When I look at other people's answer, there is one looks super clean but I have a hard time on understanding what it is doing:

```
function makeTranspose(arr) {
    return arr[0].map((x,i) => arr.map(x => x[i]));
}
```

If the arr parameter is what is shown on the example above, isn't arr[0] only returns [1, 2, 3]?   And isn't the first x already point to the individual element in arr[0]? If this is the case, how can map be used on each individual element again? This is as far as I can assume what it is doing.Please help me solve the puzzle on how it actually able to return the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

`arr[0].map` maps over `[1, 2, 3]` yes. This is a hack to get the index of each column (`i`) and it discards the elements of the row. These are assigned to the outer map's `x` variable which is never used. [The second parameter to `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), `i`, is the index of the element being processed. Aka the column index.

Then there's an **inner** map (`arr.map`) that maps over each row. This inner map runs `row count` times, for every run of the outer `column count` times map.

It's a confusing bit of code because it overwrites the variable `x` in the inner map. These naming conventions might make it more clear, using `_` to represent an *unused* argument:

```js
const transpose = (matrix) =>
    matrix[0].map((_, columnIndex) => matrix.map(row => row[columnIndex]));
```

The first time the outer map runs, it runs with `columnIndex` of `0`. Still on the first run of the outer map, it's now going to run the inner map. This runs for every row of the matrix, and will get the `columnIndex`'d value from the row. So it's building a new row, where each element is pulled from each row at the specified column.

Answer (score 1):

Its first map is being used just to get an array with the indexes of arr, and he ignores the actual value X (he overwrites it on the second map). That means, he just wants to loop from 0 to n, being n the length of arr.

That would be equivalent to

```
const makeTranspose_FirstStep = arr => arr[0]
    .map((cur, idx) => idx) // first step

makeTranspose_FistStep([ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]) // [0, 1, 2]
```

Now that he's got an array of indices (in this case [0, 1, 2]), he can use it to pluck the number out of arr and place it in the right position.

```
const makeTranspose_SecondStep = arr => arr[0]
    .map((cur, n) => n)
    .map(n => arr.map(x => x[n])) // second step
```

This second map is a bit trickier: two maps one inside the other will return a list of lists. The first map determines that there is going to be "n" arrays inside the response array.
The second map gets the nth number of each array and returns an array containing those numbers. So [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]], would return for n=1: [1, 4, 7]; and for n=2: [2, 5, 8]. (Note that the full arr is invoked again inside this map.)

My functions above were didactically broken into two steps, but they can be written more tersely, which is the original function. Notice we can ignore the first argument of the first map.

```
const mT = arr => arr[0].map((_, n) => arr.map(x => x[n]))
```

Answer (score 0):

if that can help you i added some **console.log** in...

```js
function makeTranspose(arr)
  {
  return arr[0].map((x,i) =>
    { 
    console.log(`x:${x}, i:${i}` )
    return arr.map(y =>
      {
      console.log(`-- y:${JSON.stringify(y)}, y[i]==y[${i}]:${y[i]}`)
      return  y[i]
      })  
    })
  }

let result = makeTranspose([ ['a', 'b', 'c']
                           , ['d', 'e', 'f']
                           , ['g', 'h', 'i']
                           ])
console.log ('\n')
result.forEach(line=>console.log(JSON.stringify(line)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```